# In Xul, how to get rid of the popup's background color and make it transparent?

Tags: xul

To make a window transparent, I just don't use the "window" tag. I use a "myWindow" tag, so it don't show the default window background.

But how do I do with a popup dialog?

Answer (score 0):

To make an element transparent, setting `background-color: transparent;` and/or `-moz-appearance: none;` normally suffices, it's not necessary to fiddle around with non-standard tag names.

Comment: For window it doesn't work. So, I had forgotten to try it with a popup, I'll try it Monday morning (it's Friday here! =D)

Comment: for a window it doesn't work for me, and if it works for you, that leads me to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171599/why-doesnt-background-color-works-for-my-xul-app).