# Why doesn't background-color works for my xul app?

Tags: css, window, transparency, xul

Running this xul app:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300"
    style="background-color:transparent;"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <label value="MAIN WINDOW"/>

</window>
```

my window background is showing up. Is there a way to make it transparent (without get rid of the `chrome://global/skin/`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Linux](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/1/toolkit/themes/gnomestripe/global/global.css#l72) and [Windows](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/1/toolkit/themes/winstripe/global/global.css#l68), toolkit also themes windows with `-moz-appearance: window;` so you also need to override that with `-moz-appearance: none;` if you want your window to be transparent.

Comment: Great! But what about for half transparency? The same approach is not working, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181039/how-to-make-a-50-transparent-window-in-xul